# django 1.3 - Saving multiple forms does a partial save

Tags: django, django-views, multiple-forms

I'm having some troubles making multiple forms in django. I have two models, `Space` and `Entity`. Each space can have N entities related to it.

I've created a form with two ModelForms, and writed a view that works "apparently". This is, it saves the space form, but not the data on the entity form. I does not make sense to me that saving the forms does a "partial" storage of it.

**views.py**

```
def all(items):
    import operator
    return reduce(operator.and_, [bool(item) for item in items])

def create_space(request):

    """
    Create new space with its related entities. In this view the author
    field is automatically filled.
    """
    space_form = SpaceForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    entity_forms = [EntityForm(request.POST or None, prefix=str(x)) for x in range(0,3)]

    if request.POST:
        space_form_uncommited = space_form.save(commit=False)
        space_form_uncommited.author = request.user

        if space_form.is_valid() and all([ef.is_valid() for ef in
                                          entity_forms]):
            new_space = space_form_uncommited.save()

            for ef in entity_forms:
                ef_uncommited = ef.save(commit=False)
                ef_uncommited.space = new_space
                ef_uncommited.save()
            # We add the created spaces to the user allowed spaces
            space = get_object_or_404(Space, name=space_form_uncommited.name)
            request.user.profile.spaces.add(space)
            return redirect('/spaces/' + space.url)

    return render_to_response('spaces/space_add.html',
                              {'form': space_form,
                               'entityform_0': entity_forms[0],
                               'entityform_1': entity_forms[1],
                               'entityform_2': entity_forms[2]},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class SpaceForm(ModelForm):

    """
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Space

class EntityForm(ModelForm):

    """
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
```

The template code is pasted [here](http://dpaste.org/jLRw/) because is too long.

Comment: EntityForm should be a ModelFormset, not ModelForm. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: After using formsets the Entities are being saved, but they don't get the related space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

There was some kind of problem using RAW forms. I converted EntityForm to a ModelFormSet and after that, the Entities got saved.

Fixed also the entity.space delaration, it was storing a `NoneObject`.

Final code:

**views.py**

```
def create_space(request):

    space_form = SpaceForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    entity_forms = EntityFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
                                 queryset=Entity.objects.none())

    if request.POST:
        space_form_uncommited = space_form.save(commit=False)
        space_form_uncommited.author = request.user

        if space_form.is_valid() and entity_forms.is_valid():
            new_space = space_form_uncommited.save()
            space = get_object_or_404(Space, name=space_form_uncommited.name)

            ef_uncommited = entity_forms.save(commit=False)
            for ef in ef_uncommited:
                ef.space = space
                ef.save()
            # We add the created spaces to the user allowed spaces

            request.user.profile.spaces.add(space)
            return redirect('/spaces/' + space.url)

    return render_to_response('spaces/space_add.html',
                              {'form': space_form,
                               'entityformset': entity_forms},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
EntityFormSet = modelformset_factory(Entity, extra=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create objects, ModelForm will do it for you, so remove lines `space = Space()` and `entity = Entity()` and don't pass any `instance` to forms.

And don't reinvent `all` function, it's already [Python built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all). :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the form keeps doing the same as before :/

Comment: @Oscar Carballal And what happens? No entites saved at all?

Comment: None at all. It saves the space, but not the entities